# How to add arrows to a polynomial Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am new to Tikz and PGFplots and wanted to know if there was an easy way to create arrows at the end of my function.  I a have been trying to look at the argument for `\addplot` and didn't see much. I have been trying on Google, but can't seem to pinpoint it.  Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{Graphing Tikz}
\author{nbennett }
\date{September 2020}
\pgfplotsset{my style/.append style={axis x line=middle, axis y line=
middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, axis equal }}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[my style, xtick={-3,-2,...,3},ytick={-3,-2,...,3},xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=-3,ymax=3]
    \addplot [domain=-3:3, smooth, thick,red] { x^2 };
    \end{axis}
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to add type arrows markeer to `\addplot` macro, for example :

```
\addplot [very thick,red,<->] { x^2}
```

however, you must take a care that drawing curve will not be cut by `\ymax` before it reach domain borders. In your case this mean that you need to set `\ymax=9`  (see the first example) or restrict y doiman to for example in your case to `restrict y to domain=0:3`.

In answer I'm focused only on diagram. In this I a bit change axis. I believe, that it is not difficult to revert them to what you show in your question.

Also I remove option `smooth` and instead it define `samples=101`.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}% <-- changed, that show only diagram
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]
\begin{axis}
  [
axis lines=middle, 
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
xtick={-3,-2,...,3},
ytick={0,...,9},
xmin=-3.5,xmax=3.5,
ymin=-0.5,ymax=9.5,
domain=-3:3
  ]
\addplot [very thick,red,<->] { x*x };  
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or with use `restrict y to domain=..`:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}% <-- changed, that show only diagram
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]
\begin{axis}
  [
axis lines=middle, axis equal,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
xtick={-3,-2,...,3},
ytick={0,...,3},
xmin=-3.5,xmax=3.5,
restrict y to domain=0:3,
domain=-3:3, samples=101
  ]
\addplot [very thick,red,<->] { x*x };  
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I tried the code [stealth] earlier but it did not seam to change the figure.

Comment: @NIckBennett, because you cut-off diagram with  `ymax=3`, so end of curvwe was nod drawn. You should noticem, that in the first example I set `ymax=9.5` , in the second example I restrict drawing parabola to `restrict y to domain=0:3`. Type of arrow has not any influence of it present in diagram. For example, you can remove option `[>=Stealth]` and see new result.

Comment: @NIckBennett, see added explanation to answer.