# Placing arrows on ends of function graphs based on y domain limits

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-arrows

I'm making graphs with Tikz/PGF and would like the ends of the graphs in the specified axis limits to have arrows. This is easy to do if the graph goes out the "sides" of the window by setting `domain=-10:10` or equivalent, but not as easy if the graph goes off the "top/bottom", where it's the $y$ value that needs to be cut off. Not a big deal for linear functions or other easy expressions where we can "solve" for the points in the domain where the graph would go out of bounds and restrict the $x$ domain, but this is nasty for general functions and I don't want to tweak all those domain restrictions by hand.

Trying to invoke `restrict y to domain=-11:11` doesn't seem to cut the graph at the right place, as the code below shows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=8cm,
    axis lines=center,
    axis equal image=true,
    axis line style={stealth-stealth},
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-11, xmax=11,
    xtick={-10,10},
    xticklabels={$-10$,$10$},
    ymin=-11, ymax=11,
    ytick={-10,10},
    yticklabels={$-10$,$10$},
    minor x tick num=19,
    minor y tick num=19,
    %domain=-10:10,
    %restrict x to domain=-11:11,
    restrict y to domain=-11:11,
    %y domain=-11:11,
]
\addplot[red,very thick,Stealth-Stealth]{2*x+3};
%,domain=-7:4
\node[label={180:{$(0,3)$}},circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt] at (axis cs:0,3) {};
\node[label={0:{$(1,5)$}},circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt] at (axis cs:1,5) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: code output]

It seems to stop at $y=-7$ instead of $y=-11$, and other combinations of adding/removing the commented lines or the `ymax, ymin` specifications don't seem to help. There didn't seem to be this problem in this other post: [How to add arrows to a polynomial Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565128/how-to-add-arrows-to-a-polynomial-tikz). The only thing that works is including the explicit domain for the desired range, `domain=-7:4`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Sorry, ready to go now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `domain=-11:11` and `restrict y to domain=-11:11` to the `axis` options, as this will enlarge the plot so that it covers -11 ≤ *x* ≤ 11 but also will cut away the parts where *y* < -11 and *y* > 11.

This will, however, not quite result in a plot that goes from *y* = -11 to *y* = 11, which is due to the wrong sample size. If you add `samples=23` (11 + 11 + 1, so that we get one sample for each *x* integer/step) as option to the `\addplot` command, you'll get what you're after:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=8cm,
    axis lines=center,
    axis equal image=true,
    axis line style={stealth-stealth},
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-11, xmax=11,
    xtick={-10,10},
    ymin=-11, ymax=11,
    ytick={-10,10},
    minor x tick num=19,
    minor y tick num=19,
    domain=-11:11,
    restrict y to domain=-11:11,
]
\addplot[red,very thick,Stealth-Stealth,samples=23] {2*x+3};
\node[label={180:{$(0,3)$}},circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt] at (axis cs:0,3) {};
\node[label={0:{$(1,5)$}},circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt] at (axis cs:1,5) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, you probably only need the `arrows.meta` library and can omit the `arrows` library. You can also omit `xticklabels={$-10$,$10$}` and `yticklabels={$-10$,$10$}` because this is implicitly already set via `xtick={-10,10}` and `ytick={-10,10}`.

Comment: Huh, interesting! So the default domain for any plot is not the xmax and xmin limits? In the past, I didn't need to specify the domain for a given axis size and it just "filled" the available limits in x and y (though getting the end arrows was the problem).
Also, do you happen to know what the default number of samples is (presumably also based on the domain size)?

Comment: @ArbiterKC I think you need to specify the domain here, because the plot is shifted (+3). The default `samples` value is 25 and not based on the domain.